# What is the difference between “begin” and “start”?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

**EDIT:** [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21043/what-is-the-difference-between-begin-and-start) didn't help me.

Should I say:

> This is the point where the road begins

or

> This is the point where the road starts

What about the arc endpoints instead? Should I say:

> This rope connects arc's start point and arc's end point

or

> This rope connects arc's beginning point and arc's end point

To my taste, begin works better with roads and start works better with arcs. Is it correct? Is there a reason for it?

Comment: You rarely "begin" the car.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "begin" and "start"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21043/what-is-the-difference-between-begin-and-start)

Comment: start ends in stop; begin ends in end. 2) Start is both transitive and intransitive, but begin is usually intransitive, though it can at times be transitive too. Beginning is the end in a circle; and end is the beginning, whereas start is not the stop, a and stop not start too. ;)

Comment: @Ram: so you would say the line beginning point? Doesn't it sound bad?

Comment: Usually a line starts...

Comment: @Ram: ah, so you are with me ;-)

Comment: @RamPillai - You've never heard someone begin a song?

Comment: @HotLicks, Yes, but what I commented is, 'begin' is usually intransitive, but can at times be transitive too.

Comment: @RamPillai - So there's no rule, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two words 'begin' and 'start' are very close logically, 'something has been  caused to happen', so their primary differences are collocations and connotations.

'Begin' sounds more formal and attaches to more abstract things.

'Start' is more informal and is more likely about concrete processes.

A teacher might say "Let's begin the lesson." and the student "We started studying.".

Etymologically, ['begin'](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=begin) is classic Germanic, a common cognate in all Germanic languages. ['start'](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=start), while also Germanic, was more about a movement: leap, tumble, or fall, which in ME was to flinch ('startle') and by semantic drift 'to set in motion' by Early Modern English. I mention this because usually a formal/informal word pair in English has a French/German source. But whatever the history, most of the older versions of 'start' are obsolete and is currently mostly the same as 'begin', modulo register.

As to your particular words, I don't find any preference for start or begin with road or string themselves. It is purely the context which might give a very subtle nudge for start or begin.